# How to Debug EJS code in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, debugging, ejs, canjs

I am using EJS templates with CanJS and are looking for a way to debug my EJS code. Currently firebug can show me the syntax errors in EJS but in other browsers, I am not able to see anything.I need to go through my EJS file very carefully to solve the errors. I searched on web and found out about **ejs_fulljslint** https://code.google.com/p/embeddedjavascript/ , but not able to run this properly. I included the script into my HTML file but still wasn't getting any console errors. I am not able to find a demo of debugging on web.

Can anyone tell me how to debug my EJS code. If you can provide me any example, that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have u added `ejs_jslint.js` for the hint of the error?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit I added ejs_fulljslint.js from the above mentioned link but got nothing. Can you tell me more about ejs_jslint.js ? Any link to that

Comment: ejs_jshint is the js which gives you a line no and exact error where you stuck and btw you don't know how to debug in chrome?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit I know how to debug javascript but I don't know how to debug EJS file in chrome. Also can you provide the link to ejs_jslint.js . Not able to find it on web

Comment: Are you getting it now?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit Its the same link which I have provided above(Checkout google code) Its ejs_fulljslint. I am not able to debug using it

Comment: Is your js file included in a source code? When page is rendered

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the end, EJS just translates to JavaScript and therefore just placing a **debugger;** statement where you need it and opening developer tools, might do the trick for you. For example, to check on the **i** variable in a for loop you would place your **debugger;** like this:

```
<script type="text/ejs" id="todoList">
  <% for(var i = 0; i < todos.length; ++i) { %>
    <% debugger; %>
    <li><%= this[i].attr('description') </li>
  <% } %>
</script>
```

Comment: thats the hard way around. Looking for a direct solution and JS file is not the exact replica of EJS code. It contains lots of self written code

Answer (score 0):

I always try to avoid doing serious calculation in ejs but one way to start is to check all of the arguments of `can.view` in the debugger before it enters the canjs. I find that I can usually figure out the issue from there.