# How to debug .ejs file?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, ejs

I hope to debug on some .ejs file.
It looks to me the '.ejs' is sent to browser as I find both HTML & script tag inside.

My question is
1 Is it possible  to add breakpoint to '.ejs' for debugging?
2 Is 'chrome developer tools' the right tool  I should look into?

Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `<% debugger; %>` to your `EJS` file?

Related question: [How to Debug EJS code in Chrome/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544714/how-to-debug-ejs-code-in-chrome-safari)